Help needed for decay property of the following integral
This integral looks almost like a Fourier-integral, if it wasn't for the limits:
$$\int^\infty_{\sqrt{1+1/p^2}}dx\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1/p^2}{x^2-1}}-1\right)e^{-itpx},$$
where $t$ is some positive parameter. I want to determine how the integral decays when $p\rightarrow \infty$. (I don't actually think that for any $t>0$ this changes the behaviour, but just in case, I included it. Indeed, for $t=0$, the integral goes to 1 for $p\rightarrow \infty$.)
I can't seem to approach this problem (neither using pen and paper nor Mathematica) since the standard tricks for fourier-transform fail as far as I can see. (One can extend this to the negative side and see that due to the symmetry in $x\rightarrow -x$, this is just the complex conjugate, so has the same modulus. But there is still a gap in between...)
Any help would be appreciated!

I got (not rigorously)
$$I(p)=\int^\infty_{\sqrt{1+1/p^2}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1/p^2}{x^2-1}}-1\right)e^{-itpx}dx=e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+1}-\frac{\pi i}4}\left(\sqrt\frac\pi{2tp}-\frac1p\right)+O\big(p^{-\frac32}\big)$$
Random check with WA (free option) mostly confirms the answer, though the accuracy is not fully satisfactory. The explanation could be that, handling a strongly oscillating function, higher terms can bring substantial contribution to its real/imaginary part.

@Svyatoslav How did you obtain this result - even without rigor? Did you do some integration by parts? If so, then could you elaborate on the "rest" ($\mathcal{O}(...)$) - which seems to have a similar problem when trying to determine the asymptotics.

I did not mention that the obtained asymptotics was valid for $tp\gg1$. In the case $p\gg1;, tp\ll1$ we have to use another approach, and the answer will be different. Yes, I can post the heuristic solution, but could you check the answer numerically first? WA (free option) does not allow to do it properly: I can see that the  approximation generally works, but cannot understand the approximation accuracy.

@Svyatoslav Mathematica (paid) unforunately also cannot evaluate this integral numerically. Indeed, I already tried so and could not get the numerics to converge...

This is strange... I considered separately real and imaginary parts. WA (free option) does not allow to integrate to infinity, so I had to do some manipulations (introduce a finit upper bound; check that the integral is not sensitive to the bound variations, etc.) The example of such evaluation: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%2B1%2F%2850%29%5E2%7D%7D%5E%7B100%7D%28%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2-1%2F%2850%29%5E2%7D%7Bx%5E2-1%7D%7D-1%29%5Ccos%2850x%29dx and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Ccos%2850%2B%5Cpi%2F4%29%28%5Csqrt%7B%5Cpi%2F100%7D-0.02%29

Also one more check (imaginary part) -https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-%5Cint_%7B%5Csqrt%7B1%2B1%2F%2850%29%5E2%7D%7D%5E%7B100%7D%28%5Csqrt%7B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2-1%2F%2850%29%5E2%7D%7Bx%5E2-1%7D%7D-1%29%5Csin%2850x%29dx and  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-%5Csin%28%5Csqrt%7B2501%7D%2B%5Cpi%2F4%29%28%5Csqrt%7B%5Cpi%2F100%7D-0.02%29

I think the numeric check is one of the most important steps to ensure that we are heading in the right direction, especially if we want to evaluate higher terms of the asymptotics...

@Svyatoslav Ok, I may have to use both WA and MMA in conjunction then. Since MMA currently has a bug which does not allow the integral to start at the lower bound.

@Svyatoslav Have you seen my numerical analysis? (The missing points are where MMA fails to do it numerically.)

Yes, I even marked it (+1), though I did not understand how it was related to the check of my asymptotics )

@Svyatoslav dont we need the power law of how the integral decays in $p$? I.e. the lowest power can be directly read off of this numerical analysis. And it turns out that somehow the exponent does not seem to be 1/2 like your analysis suggested, but rather closer to 0.433

IMHO, the question is simple. We have the integral and asymptotic, and the idea is to compare the numeric results. The integral is complex (so the asymptotic is), and we have to consider the real and imaginary parts separately. We can choose some $t$  (for example, $t=\frac12; 1; 2$; as I said, the asymptotic is not valid for $t=0$), and consider the integral and asymptotics values for big $p$ (for example, $p=10; 50; 100...$) This will be not a full check, but at least we will see that the asymptotic works/does not work, and see its accuracy (it should become more precise as $p$ is growing).

BTW, your integral strongly oscillate (at $t\neq0$), and does not simply decline when $p$ is growing - the real/imaginary parts change the sign ($\sim \cos(pt)/\sin (pt)$) - this is clear even without any evaluation.

@Svyatoslav This is precisely what I did. I took the modulus to make it more clear, but you are correct, the behaviour is oscillating when regarding the Re, Im parts. And the conclusion I drew is that the asymptotics derived by you (take away the $e^{i...}$, it is 1) seems to be wrong. Since my exponent is not $1/2$, but rather $0.433...$.

If my asymptotic is wrong, I'm afraid I cannot bring any valuable contribution to your problem. Anyway, I wish you good luck.

This is a temporary answer done using numerics. I calculated the modulus of the integral in question for varying $p$ at fixed $t$. Results for the leading order asymptotic (i.e. the smallest exponent in an $\frac{1}{p}$ expansion) below:
It seems the exponent is indeed $t$ independent.
For $t=0$, the modulus of the integral is convergent to a constant.
For $t=1$, we have numerically around $c=0.436$ (using a fit of the form $a/x^c$). $t=1$" />
For $t=2$ we have $c=0.432$ 
And lastly, for $t=1/2$, we have $c=0.433$. So it seems not quite a square root... 
